# Pygame - Python - 360-degree angle on a cube, cursor / pointer / mouse orientation

Tags: python, math, pygame, game-physics, angle

I am trying to solve this problem of the angle, I noticed that there are two 0,0 in the coordinates, maybe that is what is preventing the cube from making a 360 degree turn, follows the video and the code.

Can someone help me?

[video here](https://youtu.be/fpDofLgPtO4)

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import math

def main():
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 500])
    pygame.display.set_caption('Example 1')

    player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('img', 'rect.png')).convert_alpha() #path to cube ./img/rect.png

    pygame.font.init()

    font = pygame.font.get_default_font()
    font_angle = pygame.font.SysFont(font, 44, True)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) #screen background color

        player_rect = player.get_rect() #player rect (for center position)

        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #mouse position (x, y)

        #to define angle - start
        hypo = math.sqrt(math.pow(mouse_x - (player_rect[0] + player_rect.centerx), 2) +
                         math.pow(mouse_y - (player_rect[1] + player_rect.centery), 2))

        cos = (mouse_x - (player_rect[0] + player_rect.centerx)) / hypo
        sin = (mouse_y - (player_rect[1] + player_rect.centery)) / hypo

        angle = (180 / math.pi) * - math.atan2(sin, cos)
        #end

        newplayer = pygame.transform.rotate(player, angle) #rotate cube


        screen.blit(newplayer, [300, 100]) #show cube in screen

        text = font_angle.render(str("%.2f" % angle), 1, (255, 0, 0)) #show angle in mouse position

        screen.blit(text, ((mouse_x+20), mouse_y)) #show text

        pygame.display.update() #update frames

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just subtract the `player_rect.centerx` position from the `mouse_x` position (the same for `y`) and pass it to `math.atan2`:

```
dist_x = mouse_x - player_rect.centerx
dist_y = mouse_y - player_rect.centery
angle = -math.degrees(math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x))
```

Create the rect before the while loop starts and pass the desired center coordinates. Use `get_rect` to create a new rect after the image is rotated and pass the center coords of the previous rect to keep it centered. And blit the image at the `player_rect` (that means at its `topleft` coordinates).

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import math


def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 500])

    # player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('img', 'rect.png')).convert_alpha() #path to cube ./img/rect.png
    player = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.polygon(player, (100, 200, 255), [(0, 0), (50, 15), (0, 30)])
    player_rect = player.get_rect(center=(500, 250)) # player rect (for center position)

    font = pygame.font.get_default_font()
    font_angle = pygame.font.SysFont(font, 44, True)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        dist_x = mouse_x - player_rect.centerx
        dist_y = mouse_y - player_rect.centery
        angle = -math.degrees(math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x))

        newplayer = pygame.transform.rotate(player, angle)
        # Create a new rect and pass the center of the old rect.
        player_rect = newplayer.get_rect(center=player_rect.center)

        screen.blit(newplayer, player_rect) # Blit it at the player_rect.
        text = font_angle.render(str("%.2f" % angle), 1, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, ((mouse_x+20), mouse_y))
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, long after I created the post I came up with a solution too.